# Jenkins rebuild for job triggered by github pull requests builder

Tags: jenkins

Can the [GitHub pull request builder](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/GitHub+pull+request+builder+plugin) work with the [Rebuild](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Rebuild+Plugin) plugin?

Correctly `rebuild` can see all the parameters of a `github pr builder` triggered build, but these parameters are not used for some reason. A rebuild of the rebuild will show no parameters.

I know I can trigger a build by commenting on a PR, but sometimes I find it's convenient to rebuild from Jenkins (e.g. build fails -> click the Jenkins link on the PR and get to the failed build -> it's a flaky spec -> rebuild).

Answer (score 2):

Go to your Jenkins job and check the option "Rebuild Without Asking For Parameters". When you click "Rebuild" it'll trigger a new build with same parameters.

[Job Rebuild Options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fvDQ3.png)